# How to get this type of array from string.xml file to an android activity

Tags: android

[photo of the integer array in string.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rLz2S.png)

I want to access this integer array into an arraylist in activity.

Comment: If you need an Array-List as you mentioned, please refer my answer, else there are many other answers below that you can use.

Answer (score 0):

You can access this array as following:

```
int[] photos = context.getResources().getIntArray(R.array.photo);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
Int[] intarray = getResources().getIntArray(R.string.photo);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you are asking how to pass this to an Intent or how to convert it to ArrayList.
If it is the former:

1) Use the Bundle from the Intent:

```
Intent mIntent = new Intent(this, Example.class);
Bundle extras = mIntent.getExtras();
extras.putString(key, value);
```

2) Create a new Bundle

```
Intent mIntent = new Intent(this, Example.class);
Bundle mBundle = new Bundle();
mBundle.putString(key, value);
mIntent.putExtras(mBundle);
```

If you are asking about the latter try:

```
Resources r = getResources();
int[] p = r.getIntArray(R.array.photo);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

Create an `Array-List` of `Integers`:

```
public ArrayList<Integer> photoList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Then,

```
photoList = Arrays.asList(context.getResources().getIntArray(R.array.photo));
```

This will give you as `ArrayList`

Hope it helps.